# Defining defaultProps in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any differences between the following two ways of defining **defaultProps** in React?

```
class ReactComp extends React.Component {}
ReactComp.defaultProps = {}
```

OR

```
class ReactComp extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {}
}
```

Comment: No. The both works in the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are no different. They both are `static` in nature. The first one is the Property provided by React [`defaultprops`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) if you are using the ES6 `class` syntax and the other one is to declare the props in the ESNext way. (nothing to do with React).

You can find more info on the [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword on MDN.